# How much memory is allocated to query node(s) of Milvus?

Tags: milvus

I am working with Milvus standalone (v2.2.6). In Milvus limitations it is specified that the data to be loaded has to be less than 90% of the memory allocated to the query node(s). I have a requirement where I need to know how much memory is allocated to the query node(s). I tried searching online but couldn't get one. How to find out what is the total memory allocated to the query node(s)?